# Set Formik form (child component) to initial values when parent modal is closed react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog, state, formik

I have a Login page using Formik form (Child component) and a Modal (Parent component).

Issue is - When i type something in Formik form (Child component) and close the Modal (Parent component) without submitting and try to open it again it still show the previous values.

I want to set the Formik values to initial when i close the modal. If i was using react state would be easy but i'm using formik that's why I'm confuse.

**Login Formik form (Child component)**

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import './Registration.css'
import { useFormik, Field, Form, Formik, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import schema from '../Schema/index'
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { outlinedInputClasses } from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import { inputLabelClasses } from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import axios from 'axios';
import loginSchema from '../Schema/login';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import signIn from '../redux/actions';
import signOut from '../redux/action2';
import logo from '../assets/images/The_Writer.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Login.css'



function Login({ From, currentPath, changeModalLogin }) {


const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();
const dispatch = useDispatch();



const formik = useFormik({


    initialValues: {

        email: "",
        password: "",

    },
    validationSchema: loginSchema,

    onSubmit: (values) => {
        const data = {
            email: values.email,
            password: values.password,
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:9000/auth/login', data, { withCredentials: true })
            .then((res) => {
                alert(res.data.message || res.data.error)

                if (res.data.message) {
                    dispatch(signIn());
                    if (location.state?.from) {
                        console.log(location.state, 'state login')
                        navigate(location.state.from);
                    } else {
                        if (currentPath) {
                            changeModalLogin(false)
                        } else {
                            navigate("/")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            .catch((err) => {
                alert(err.response.data.error)
            })

    }
})

return (
    <div className='Registration'>
        <div className='login'>
            <div className='registration__main'>
                <div className='image__logo'>
                    <img alt='logo' src={logo} />
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className='textfield__wrapper'>
                        <TextField
                            error={formik.errors.email && formik.touched.email ? true : false}
                            className='mui__textfield' id="email" name="email" label="Email" variant="standard"
                            value={formik.values.email} onChange={formik.handleChange} onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            helperText={formik.touched.email ? formik.errors.email : ""}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='textfield__wrapper'>
                        <TextField
                            error={formik.errors.password && formik.touched.password ? true : false}
                            className='mui__textfield' id="password" name="password" label="Password" variant="standard"
                            value={formik.values.password} onChange={formik.handleChange} onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            helperText={formik.touched.password ? formik.errors.password : ""}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <Button type='submit' variant="contained">Login</Button>
                    <Link to="/register">  <p style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>Register</p></Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Login
```

**Modal (Parent component)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';
import "./Modal.css"
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import Login from "../../Pages/Login"
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";





function ModalAntComment({ modalLogin, changeModalLogin, From }) {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();

const handleOk = () => {
    if (From == 'plus-button') {
        navigate("/createPost")
    } else {
        navigate("/")
    }
}
const [hi, setHi] = useState(false);

const change = (value) => {
    setHi(value)
}

return (
    <Modal
        title="Login Required"
        centered
        visible={modalLogin}
        onOk={handleOk}
        okText={"Login"}
        footer={null}
        bodyStyle={{
            height: "390px"
        }}

        onCancel={() => {

            changeModalLogin(false)
            setHi(true)
        }}
    >
        <div className='right__content'>
            <Login
                currentPath={location.pathname}
                changeModalLogin={changeModalLogin}
                initialValueEmail={""}
                initialValuePass={""}
                hi={hi}
                change={change}

            />
        </div>
    </Modal >

)
}

export default ModalAntComment
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use a React key on the `Login` component that is coupled to the modals open/closed "state" such that when the modal is open and rendering the `Login` component it is a new instance.

Example:

```
function ModalAntComment({ modalLogin, changeModalLogin, From }) {
  ...

  return (
    <Modal
      title="Login Required"
      centered
      visible={modalLogin}
      onOk={handleOk}
      okText={"Login"}
      footer={null}
      bodyStyle={{
        height: "390px"
      }}
      onCancel={() => {
        changeModalLogin(false);
        setHi(true);
      }}
    >
      <div className='right__content'>
        <Login
          key={modalLogin} // <-- set React key
          currentPath={location.pathname}
          changeModalLogin={changeModalLogin}
          initialValueEmail={""}
          initialValuePass={""}
          hi={hi}
          change={change}
        />
      </div>
    </Modal >
  );
}
```

An alternative is to invoke the [`handleReset`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlereset---void) formik callback in the `Login` component, i.e. `formik.handleReset()`, to reset the form state. For this you'd need to pass in a prop from `ModalAntComment` to `Login` that the modal is open and `Login` would need to use a `useEffect` hook to listen to changes on this prop to issue the side-effect of resetting form state.

It may look something like:

```
function ModalAntComment({ modalLogin, changeModalLogin, From }) {
  ...

  return (
    <Modal
      title="Login Required"
      centered
      visible={modalLogin}
      onOk={handleOk}
      okText={"Login"}
      footer={null}
      bodyStyle={{
        height: "390px"
      }}
      onCancel={() => {
        changeModalLogin(false);
        setHi(true);
      }}
    >
      <div className='right__content'>
        <Login
          modalLogin={modalLogin} // <-- pass modalLogin as prop
          currentPath={location.pathname}
          changeModalLogin={changeModalLogin}
          initialValueEmail={""}
          initialValuePass={""}
          hi={hi}
          change={change}
        />
      </div>
    </Modal >
  );
}
```

...

```
function Login({ From, currentPath, changeModalLogin, modalLogin }) {
  ...

  const formik = useFormik({
    ...
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!modalLogin) { // <-- check if modal closed & reset
      formik.handleReset();
    }
  }, [formik, modalLogin]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```